# How to merge multiple dataviews into one?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, ado.net, dataview

I have three dataviews (dataview1, dataview2, and dataview3). These are of type System.Data.DataView, and all three have the same columns. Is there an easy way to merge them into one, so I have one dataview with rows from dataview1, followed by dataview2, and then dataview3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Dim dataview1 As DataView = new DataView()
Dim dataview2 As DataView = new DataView()

'' given the tables are not null you can then merge like this

dataview1.Table.Merge(dataview2.Table)
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I somehow missed that!

Comment: Please flag as "Answered" if this is what you were looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Afaik this will not really merge the DataViews but the underlying Tables, ie all RowFilters will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

```
DataTable datatableMerge = dataview1.ToTable();
datatableMerge.Merge(dataview2.ToTable());
```

The result includes only the rows according to the the DataViews' Filters.

Comment: FYI, This only works if the dataviews have the same columns.